# C# для Unity.Изучение

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как изучить С# для Unity?Я думаю что есть разница между обычным си шарпом и для Unity.

Answer (score 3):

Нет, разницы практически нет, разве что версия языка в Unity несколько отстает от актуальной. Все дело в предметной области - если обычный программист работает со стандартной библиотекой и через нее взаимодействует с ОС, то в Unity ты имеешь дело с движком и его API, объектами, классами и т.д. Основа одна - так что сам язык можно учить просто как обычно в отрыве от Unity. Синтаксис, алгоритмы, классы и паттерны - все это актуально для любого программирования. Почитайте книги "Язык программирования C# 5.0 и платформа .NET 4.5" Троелсана - например, я ее старую редакцию в свое время прочел - только вас там разделы типа WPF не должны, по идее, интересовать. Кто там еще - Рихтер, хоть на первый взгляд нафиг в контексте Юнити не сдался - но для общего образования как программиста книга любопытная. Ну и практика, практика и еще раз практика. Без этого никак. Знавал людей которые ничерта не смыслили в программировании и в теории полный ноль - но благодаря обширной практики и усидчивости делали готовые и работающие вещи, пусть внутри говнокод - но это работало и многим даже давало работу и доход. Правда потом они все равно сталкивались с необходимостью подтягивать свой уровень и такое обучение им вставало определенным образом боком - но то совсем иная история.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы изучить C# для Юнити, надо кодить. Выдумываешь себе небольшой проектик и пишешь, все возникающие вопросы решаешь гуглингом и вопросами на тематических форумах. С# на Юнити ничем не отличается от классического, разве что версия немного устаревшая. Но раз уж ты работаешь с юнитевскими объектами - то и синтаксис будет тот, который заложили разработчики движка. Но опять же без базовых знаний ООП лучше не набивать шишки, базу надо знать.